# Which option controls the color of this text?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tooltip, color-scheme

I have applied a color theme called Vibrant Ink (or some modification of it), and since I installed [Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) all my statement completion boxes are unreadable.

[undreadable http://img139.imageshack.us/img139/7876/undreadable.png](http://img139.imageshack.us/img139/7876/undreadable.png).

What setting changes the colors of these boxes? Preferrably, I'd like to change the background color to something darker, but if that's not possible at least I want to change the text color.

**Update:** I changed the `SignatureHelpTooltipBackground` setting under Tools->Options...->Environment->Fonts and colors, but this doesn't seem to affect the tooltips when editing JavaScript.

Is there another setting for JS colors, or is this a bug in VS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "default" ToolTip style has hard-coded colors that will only be different if you are running in high-contrast mode. Otherwise, it will be the light gray gradient you see in the picture above.

The tooltips in the ProPack for VB/C# files use a custom (configurable) style as you noted above.

Please submit feedback that the default tooltip background color should be configurable. The more customer requests are heard for this issue, the higher the likelihood it will be fixed in a future release:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: I've filed a request there and MS have responded with "we're currently reviewing the issue...". I have no idea what it means, but I assume that someone has at least read the ticket :P https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/572078/tooltip-backgrounds-for-javascript-should-be-configurable

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is legal or not, we can always disassemble the code and modify (patch) what we want. In this case, find that gray color in assembly and change it. It shouldn't be hard for someone who knows .NET and hexes well.